# Laravel email queue infinite processing?

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-5, amazon-sqs

I am using Laravel 5.4 with AWS SQS. I have tested it to jobs that are doing all sort of stuff and it works fine, however when I try to queue an email I get:

```
[2017-08-18 09:21:48] Processing: App\Mail\WelcomeEmail
[2017-08-18 09:21:48] Processing: App\Mail\WelcomeEmail
[2017-08-18 09:21:48] Processing: App\Mail\WelcomeEmail
[2017-08-18 09:21:48] Processing: App\Mail\WelcomeEmail
[2017-08-18 09:21:49] Processing: App\Mail\WelcomeEmail
[2017-08-18 09:21:49] Processing: App\Mail\WelcomeEmail
[2017-08-18 09:21:49] Processing: App\Mail\WelcomeEmail
[2017-08-18 09:21:49] Processing: App\Mail\WelcomeEmail
[2017-08-18 09:21:49] Processing: App\Mail\WelcomeEmail
[2017-08-18 09:21:49] Processing: App\Mail\WelcomeEmail
[2017-08-18 09:21:49] Processing: App\Mail\WelcomeEmail
[2017-08-18 09:21:49] Processing: App\Mail\WelcomeEmail
[2017-08-18 09:21:49] Processing: App\Mail\WelcomeEmail
[2017-08-18 09:21:49] Processing: App\Mail\WelcomeEmail
[2017-08-18 09:21:49] Processing: App\Mail\WelcomeEmail
[2017-08-18 09:21:50] Processing: App\Mail\WelcomeEmail
[2017-08-18 09:21:50] Processing: App\Mail\WelcomeEmail
[2017-08-18 09:21:50] Processing: App\Mail\WelcomeEmail
[2017-08-18 09:21:50] Processing: App\Mail\WelcomeEmail
[2017-08-18 09:21:50] Processing: App\Mail\WelcomeEmail
[2017-08-18 09:21:50] Processing: App\Mail\WelcomeEmail
```

And as you guess that goes however, if I send it without the queue it works absolutely fine.

Here's the code where it's executed,

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    Mail::to($data['email'])
        ->queue(new WelcomeEmail());
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

WelcomeEmail:

```
{
    return $this->from('support@dev.com')
                ->view('emails.welcomeEmail')
                ->attach('pdf/tc.pdf',[
                    'as' => 'tc.pdf',
                    'mime' => 'application/pdf',
                    ]);
}
```

welcomeEmail blade

```
<body>
    <h4>hello</h4>
    <img src="{{ $message->embed(public_path('images/logo.png')) }}" ) }}"> 

<b>We search high and low across city to bring you as much information content as possible, personalised to your interests!</b>

<p>We'll bring you all the latest live restaurant deals, sports events, travel info, show times, and much much more. If there's something you need to know or something exciting going on, you'll be the first to know about it.</p>

<p>Log in to your account and start customising your alerts today!</p>

<a class="btn btn-success" href="http://localhost:8000/profile">View Your Profile!</a>

</body>
```

Comment: Are the emails actually sent? The queued item might throw an error which makes the queue retry this action over and over.

Comment: if I don't queue the email so I just send it normally, it works fine, when i queue I never get the email however in SQS apparently it has been send because it gives me time when it was sended

Comment: @PrzemekWojtas - do you mean SES rather than SQS?

Comment: No I mean SQS i know what I mean