# How to process email queued in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5, amazon-sqs

I've a AWS SQS, and I successfully created a notification system which saves the message in the AWS SQS queue.

In the code:

```
protected function saveNotificationEmail($subject, $msg)
{                          
    Mail::to(       
        $this->getUserRecord()->email
    )->queue(new Alert($subject, $msg));
}
```

The object "Alert" has been created via CLI `php artisan make:mail Alert`.

Now, when I run the code, the queue has a new item; so everything works fine for putting the data into the queue.
When I run `php artisan queue:work`, I get series of messages like the following:

```
[2018-09-25 22:37:43] Processing: App\Mail\Alert
[2018-09-25 22:37:48] Processing: App\Mail\Alert
[2018-09-25 22:37:52] Processing: App\Mail\Alert
[2018-09-25 22:37:57] Processing: App\Mail\Alert
```

Looking at the AWS SQS, the messages are taken (Messages in Flight) and then moved back again in the queue like available to be processed..
I tested the emailing system without the `queue` method, and it's working fine.
What am I missing?

I guess the problem is very similar to this question which didn't had answer

- [Laravel email queue infinite processing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45754761/laravel-email-queue-infinite-processing)

Comment: What setting do you have in `.env` for your `QUEUE_DRIVER` and what does your `config/queue.php` file look like?

Comment: QUEUE_DRIVER=sqs
In the config/queue.php file I have the 'sqs' subarray configured with the AWS SQS credentials. I guess this bit it's working fine because the code is able to place the message in the queue

Answer (score 1):

The problem was related to the view, as I didn't pass the variable the template was expecting.
Using the CLI command `php artisan queue:listen -vvv` wasn't showing anything relevant, I found more info in the log file storage/log/laravel.log

Comment: Your answer helped me fix the same error showing up when database queue on Laravel 5.5. The cause for mine is that I didn't declare the variable passed to the constructor in the class even though I initialised it within the constructor. The fix was declaring the property in the class.